# Align item vertically with semantic-ui-react

Tags: css, styled-components, semantic-ui-react

I am having such code written in `semantic-ui-react`:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const StyledMultiselect = styled(Multiselect)`
  width: 20em !important;
`

<Grid>
    <Grid.Row>
      <Grid.Column width={6}>
        <InlineHeader content="Add Project:" />
        <StyledMultiselect
          placeholder="Select project"
          onChange={(v) => addElement(processAddedElement ? processAddedElement({ key: v }) : v)} 
          options={projectNames}
          inline
        />
      </Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column width={6}>
        <InlineHeader content="Add Project Group:"/>
        <StyledMultiselect
          placeholder="Select project group"
          onChange={(v) => addProjectGroup(v, addElement)}
          options={projectGroupNames}
          inline
        />
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid.Row>
  </Grid>
```

Where `InlineHeader` is:

```
export const InlineHeader = styled(({ marginTop, ...props }) => <Header {...props} />)`
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em !important;
  margin-top: ${props => props.marginTop || "0em"} !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  
  .sub.header {
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin-left: 0.5em !important;
  }
```

What I see is the following:

[image]

And I want header and select field to be aligned vertically. I am able to place `InlineHeader` and `StyledMultiselect` in different `Grid.Column` and align them using `marginTop` property, but then the behavior for screen resizing is much worse and they are horizontally spaced too far. If they are in one `Grid.Column`, then `marginTop` applied to `InlineHeader` does not work. I tried putting `InlineHeader` in `span` and applying styles but that fails to work either. Applying `marginTop` or `paddingTop` to `StyledMultiselect` does not work. Any ideas on how to vertically align them in a single `Grid.Column`?

> Update

What I noticed is that the positioning is correct until I add `multiple` on the `semantic-ui-react` `Form.Dropdown` (`StyledMultiselect`), so the following is positioned correctly vertically:

```
<Form.Dropdown
  placeholder="Select project"
  inline
  selection
/>
```

But if we add `multiple` it slides down in its vertical position (see screenshot above):

```
<Form.Dropdown
  placeholder="Select project"
  inline
  selection
  multiple
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the multi-select type input in the original CSS for SUI, not in the React classnames. It looks like you are trying to fight those to make this work. There is only a one line CSS change needed that should resolve this for you. It also involves using the correct accessible `<label>` tag for that input instead of using a Header component.

```css
.ui.form .inline.field > .multiple.selection.dropdown {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Here is a codesandbox with this single line CSS fix](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-inline-multi-select-css-e2u7i?file=/example.css) that you can apply as necessary to your project, depending on how you are handling your styles.

[image]